# If i publish an book in iBooks can I get the buyers information?

Tags: ios4, ipad, ibooks

If i publish an book in iBooks can I get the buyers information?
Does apple offer some way to get the information of my buyers. I want to know what a buyer both and his email address so I can include in some specific campaign.

Comment: Terente, did this answer help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apple doesn't allow you access to any information about the folks who have downloaded your iBook, so you won't be able to get email addresses. You do have access to geographic location, and breakdowns by week, day, month, etc, which DOES give you the ability to see how your sales are affected by other campaigns you decide to pursue. You can find all of this inside [iTunes Connect.](https://itunesconnect.apple.com/)